# Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined when using quasar components in storybook story

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook, quasar-framework

I'm having an issue with rendering quasar components in the storybook with Vue and Quasar. I suspect it's not finding the quasar tags in the story. I just followed these steps to set up the project https://quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin and then I ran `npx sb init` to set up the storybook in my app. After all, compilation works fine but when I view my story on the storybook screen I got the below error that appears. You check the screen here https://prnt.sc/1qd3ywr

I tried all possible solutions but none had worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined
    at setup (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:89474:322262)
    at callWithErrorHandling (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:37183:22)
    at setupStatefulComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:44151:29)
    at setupComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:44107:11)
    at mountComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:42108:13)
    at processComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:42083:17)
    at patch (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:41698:21)
    at componentEffect (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:42220:21)
    at reactiveEffect (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:36022:24)
    at effect (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:35997:9)
```

Here is my story for the quasar component: (quasar.stories.js)

```
import { QLayout, QPageContainer, QPage, QSelect, QBtn } from 'quasar'

export default {
  title: 'Quasar'
}

export const Components = () => ({
  title: 'QuasarComponents',
  components: { QLayout, QPageContainer, QPage, QSelect, QBtn },
  template: `<q-layout>
    <q-page-container>
      <q-page class="full-height full-width justify-center items-center q-pa-xl">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <q-input v-model="name" label="Full name" />
          <q-select v-model="role" :options="options" label="User Role" />
        </div>
      </q-page>
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>`,
  data () {
    return {
      name: null,
      role: 'User',
      options: ['Admin', 'Supervisor', 'User']
    }
  }
})
```

main.js

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ]
}
```

preview.js

```
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862250/cannot-read-property-screen-of-undefined-in-vuequasarstorybook

Comment: @tony19 Never mind, I was in the wrong login. Can you please suggest some solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like  [GitHub issue #7263](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/7263), which is caused by an app extension.

One user discovered a [solution](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/7263#issuecomment-647023821):

> em-qui is an app-extension that was also declaring quasar as a devDependency (for IDE support...), though on the same version this was somehow causing a confict:
>
> ```js
> {
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
>     "quasar": "^1.12.6"
>   },
> }
> ```
>
> So I had to separate the two by declaring it in peerDependencies in the app extension:
>
> ```js
> {
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3"
>   },
>   "peerDependencies": {
>     "quasar": "^1.12.6"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> and the error went away.